# How can I install a water inlet for a dishwasher?

Tags: plumbing, pipe, dishwasher

I am trying to figure out how to add a cold water inlet under the kitchen sink. The easiest thing seems to add a tee joint. Here is the picture of the cold water pipe going into the sink

[image: http://imgur.com/WRxm0.] I seem to need a [Washing Machine Tee Valve](http://www.wickes.co.uk/red-plastic-wallplugs/invt/420071/)

[image]

But the part I am not sure about is how would it fit into the current joint correctly. Would I need an adopter of some sort?

Added:
The dishwasher only takes in cold water and has plastic end which can fit right into the valve or the single end of the Y joint. The current white flexi pipe is going in to the sink. I also have this strange stop valve type thing on the middle white pipe, what is that? Can it be used?

[image]

Comment: Just as an aside, not really central to the discussion; if I were a licensed plumber looking under this sink, I am pretty sure I'd be having conniptions about the condition of this plumbing; it's a patchwork quilt of compression fittings and hot-taps for things that obviously are no longer there. The next time you have a few hundred bucks to spend on home improvement, I'd hire someone to come in, rip all this out and start fresh from the pipe coming out of the wall.

Comment: @KeithS you are absolutely right. We just moved in to this property we are renting and thats the feeling I got when i looked under the hood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where does the hose in that image currently go? Is that an existing dishwasher inlet or does it go somewhere else like a laundry closet or to a sprayer/sink?

Also, we need to know what type of fitting the dishwasher inlet will be. Most that I know of are threaded flex hose.

The part you show does not look like what you want, if you just want to screw it into your existing fitting. This part designed to be inserted into the middle of an ordinary copper pipe using compression fittings that join to an unthreaded copper or nylon pipe end, providing a ball-valve connection in the middle of that pipe suitable for a washing machine. You CAN use this, especially since you have a shutoff valve (which appears to have been installed in much the same way), but you must permanently alter your plumbing by cutting some part of the pipe in half to put this fitting in.

What you probably want is a male-male-female NPT equal tee or Y fitting, allowing you to screw in a second hose exactly like the one you have now. Something like this (from the same site) may fit the bill:

[image]

If you can find it in nickel-steel, it'll last a little longer, but this plastic fitting should be perfectly fine. Simple, near tool-less (just a pair of slip-joint pliers or a small strap wrench to tighten down the hoses), and undoable.

Comment: Taking a tip from you. I used this http://www.wickes.co.uk/red-plastic-wallplugs/invt/194579/ and http://www.wickes.co.uk/invt/420071 . Replaced the flexi pipe and it all worked like a charm :)